# How to add a submenu after X number of <li> with Javascript or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have in HTML

```
<div class="ktmsg">
  <ul>
    <li class="a1">
        <a title="Link Tools" href="#"> … </a>
    </li>
    <li class="a2">
        <a title="Link Tools" href="#"> … </a>
    </li>
    <li class="a3">
        <a title="Link Tools" href="#"> … </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

What i want to do is to add after the second `</li>` an `<ul><a href="#">More</a></ul>`
Final expected output should be

```
<div class="ktmsg">
  <ul>
    <li class="a1">
        <a title="Link Tools" href="#"> … </a>
    </li>
    <li class="a2">
        <a title="Link Tools" href="#"> … </a>
    </li>
    <ul> //Starting the sub-menu
    <a href="#">More</a> // The link that after i hover it will start showing the <li> starting from the third one
      <li class="a3">
        <a title="Link Tools" href="#"> … </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I am thinking that the javascript would look smth like this:

```
limenu = document.selectAll(.ktmsg)('<li>');
for(var i=1, i<2, i++)
  remove.limenu
  add.
```

.... And i am quite stuck, Please help, would be much appreciated.

Comment: once you hover it whether is has to be hidden if you move out of it

Comment: @ArunPJohny If you move out of it yes, it should hide again like a normal sub-menu. I was thinking with removing and adding like remove.limenu and document.create or something like that.

Comment: I am thinking that your javascript shouldn't look anything like that, as it doesn't look like valid javascript at all. I'm also thinking that your expected outcome is invalid markup, with the LI inside the anchor etc ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $lis = $('.ktmsg > ul > li');
    var $a = $('<li><a href="#">More</a></li>').insertAfter($lis.eq(1));
    var $lefts = $lis.slice(2).hide();

    $a.hover(function () {
        clearTimeout($a.data('hoverTimer'));
        $lefts.show();
    }, function () {
        var timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $lefts.hide();
        }, 200);
        $a.data('hoverTimer', timer);
    });

    $lefts.hover(function () {
        clearTimeout($a.data('hoverTimer'));
    }, function () {
        var timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $lefts.hide();
        }, 200);
        $a.data('hoverTimer', timer);
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3Ry3x)

Comment: Exactly what i wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery to add this:

```
<ul><a href="#">More</a></ul>
```

after second li you need:

```
$( 'li:eq(1)' ).after( '<ul><a href="#">More</a></ul>' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a **[fiddle of how this could work](http://jsfiddle.net/b2znC/)** using jQuery. Pretty simple really, you just hide the sub menu using CSS and then show/hide it as needed using jQuery when "More" is being hovered over. I've used `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` but you could just as easily use `hide()` and `show()` if you don't need the animations. I've restructured your HTML slightly so if you use my solution use my new HTML.